# Test Users for Facebook Account Kit?

Tags: account-kit, facebook-account-kit

In the past with the FB API, you could use the developer portal to create test accounts, and then use their tokens for testing the API. We would use these Test User tokens in our tests, CI, etc.

How come there aren't Test Users for Account Kit? When I use my Test User access tokens with the Account Kit API, they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of test user for Account Kit. You would have to test with your own phone number or email.